# cp -R: create special files rather than copying them as normal files

Tags: unix, cp

Reading up on `cp -R`, what do these mean:

- `create special files rather than copying them as normal files`
- `Created directories have the same mode as the corresponding source directory, unmodified by the process' umask`

I assume by mode they mean for example `0755`.

Answer (score 1):

You're right about mode.

The "special files" are for instance soft-links (ln -s). Using `cp -R` you will create another soft-link, rather than a copy of the file that the link points to.